# Webkit Scrollbars in one place, not another

Tags: css

I'm using webkit scrollbars in a scrollable div. That's working great. However, I'd like the actual page's scrollbars to be the OS default. How can I use CSS selectors to make the webkit scrollbars only apply to the div? An example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zxj4m/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apply the styles to the scrollbars like so:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { ... }
```

Those are pseudo-selectors. To only apply them to a certain class, prepend the class name like so:

```
.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { ... }
```

By leaving it blank, the browser assumes you're using the universal select (`*`), which applies to every single element on the page.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I feel dumb. I was adding a space between .box and ::